# TurboGears2/SQLAlchemy: Inserting a new row into a table with an autoincrement Primary Key

Tags: sqlalchemy, turbogears, turbogears2

I am a noob and am trying to get my head around TG2 and SQLAlchemy.  The specific problem I am wrestling with at the moment is how to insert a new row into a table when the PK field is configured as autoincrement.

For example:

in my myproject.model.myproject.py file I defined the following table:

```
class Dj(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'djs'

    #{ Columns

    djID = Column(Integer,  autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    djname = Column(String)
    djwebpage = Column(String)
    #}
```

In my websetup.py file I populate it with some initial data.  Since this is the first row of data, I cheated and just defined the djID to be "1"

```
dj = model.Dj("1", "DJ Anonymous", "http://www.djanonymous.com")
```

If I wanted the websetup.py to create a second row in the djs table (via object Dj)  how would I do that?

I previously tried a number of different things and have had no luck.   For example If I used the same format but did only included 2 strings (for the djname and djwebpage columns)  I get an error complaining that I did not give it enough arguments.

Of course, ultimately, I need to figure out how to create a controller to allow me to insert new entries into the table... but I'll take my learning a step at a time and be grateful just to successfully pre-populate the table with multiple rows via the websetup.py file.  Hopefully that will give me the clues to allow me to take it to the next step.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your problem is simply (I'm impressed it went unanswered for so long :).

- First why name your id column "djID"? why not just id?
- Second you **don't** insert into it, that is why it's autoincrement.
- Third the [first basic](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#creating-table-class-and-mapper-all-at-once-declaratively) SA tutorial explains this